# SaltStack Can't get Master config variables to minion

Tags: python, salt-stack

New to SaltStack. I'm writing a custom returner for salt but the minion does not seem to be able to see config variables set in the master (/etc/salt/master). I have things like connection info which need to be passed to the minion.

```
__salt__['config.option']('returner.myconfig.test')
```

comes back empty and so does this

```
__opts__.get('returner.myconfig.test', None)
```

is there something I have to enable to pass configs to minion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option in the master config named `pillar_opts` whose default was recently changed from `True` to `False`.

If you set `pillar_opts` to `True` and restart the salt-master daemon you should see the options in the master config made available to the minions.

It was changed to default to `False` because many users didn't want the minions to see all the master's config options.

Like [ahus1 mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32519530), you may want to put that configuration in pillar data or the minion config.

Answer (score 1):

Returners run on minions, therefore they are configured in the minion configuration. See for example the [Kafka returner](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/returners/all/salt.returners.kafka_return.html).

The minion configuration is read on the minion's start, therefore it is difficult to update.

As you write a custom returner: consider putting the configuration in a [pillar](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/stage/topics/pillar/index.html) instead. This way you should be able to update it without restarting the minion.

There's an option in the master config named `pillar_opts` that allow master configuration values to be available on the minons (see Utah_Dave's answer below). But as this publishes all master configuration values to the minions it can be a security issue.

Comment: Thank you for the response! So in the documentation for something like the postgres returner (https://docs.saltstack.com/en/stage/ref/returners/all/salt.returners.postgres.html) at the top where it says "the following values configured in the minion or master config:" this is inaccurate?

Comment: As https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/returners/ states returners run on the minion to forward the results of commands. Some returners can also be used on the master to forward events (but not all of them). As long as `pillar_opts` is not activated, you will need to put the options for your returner in the right file depending on the use of the returner. I will also update my answer with @utah_dave's answer.